# Connect to two tables

Tags: c#, .net, combobox

I have created comboBox and filled with one column, after I choose item from the combobox I would like to show other column in the textboxs so I wrote code to make it happen but what if I want to choose column from another table I mean I would like to show couple of columns from two different table in the textbox when I hit the combobox
Here is my code:

```
private void comboLname_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string conn = "Data Source=srv-db-02;Initial Catalog=rmsmasterdbtest;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=test;Password=*******";
    string Query = "select * from rmsmasterdbtest.dbo.customer where LastName= '" + comboLname.Text + "' ;";
    SqlConnection Myconn = new SqlConnection(conn);
    SqlCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCommand(Query, Myconn);
    SqlDataReader Reader;
    try
    {
        Myconn.Open();
        Reader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
        while (Reader.Read())
        {
            string ID = Reader.GetInt32(Reader.GetOrdinal("ID")).ToString();
            string AccountNuber = Reader.GetString(Reader.GetOrdinal("AccountNumber"));
            //string Time = Reader.GetString(Reader.GetOrdinal("Time"));
            // string Deposit = Reader.GetString(Reader.GetOrdinal("Deposit"));
            string sstatus = Reader.GetString(Reader.GetOrdinal("status"));
            string slastname = Reader.GetString(Reader.GetOrdinal("lastname"));
            txtid.Text = ID;
            txtacnum.Text = AccountNuber;
            //txttime.Text = Time;
            //txtdeposit.Text = Deposit;
            txtstatus.Text = sstatus;
            txtlname.Text = slastname;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        Myconn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider rewording your question. It's hard to understand.

Comment: Lookup how Sql Joins work http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/t-sql-starters-data-retrieval-joins

Comment: What I was trying to explain is how can I display data in my textboxs when I select some item in the combobox so I could make it as you see in the code above but still I would like to to display more columns from other tables for now I display just for one table and it is working fine.

Comment: here is my string example:string Query = "select * from rmsmasterdbtest.dbo.customer where LastName= '" + comboLname.Text + "' ;"; - how can I add another table? I hope I was clear enough and sorry about my English as it is not my first language